# On-screen display driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need write linux kernel module that will display message box over all other windows on the screen. And I need drawing image in the kernel, access to this picture from user-space application is not required. I don't understand how to do this. What framework should I use - framebuffers or v4l? I suppose direct programming of the display controller is not a good idea, because there is other driver in the kernel that already do this. So, the questions are: how to interact between in-kernel drivers, and how to specify that my picture should be on top?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can not be done in this way, since the kernel does not handle GUIs and it especially does not handle window systems. It provides access to video output devices in one form or another, but all the actual drawing and compositing of a screen is done in user space.

Now, a kernel module would have the power to just overwrite the frame buffer, but, as you noticed, there are multiple interfaces for different purposes. Additionally, using 3D rendering even for 2D desktops is quite common. Hijacking a 3D command stream for your purposes would be disproportionately difficult.

Even if you managed all that, there is no guarantee that the user space window system wouldn't just overwrite your message box immediately. Maybe even before it reaches the display.

So no, it can't be done in any practical way directly from the kernel. Your best alternative would be a user space daemon displaying the message on your kernel code's behalf through the standard channels like any other GUI program.

Comment: But why I can't implement fake write() handler for user-space application, and draw real image in the kernel module, when appropriate callback function is called by kernel framework? I want only display ready .bmp image (like logo) over all other things on the screen.

Comment: First, intercepting a write for another driver isn't supposed to happen so there is no clean way. Second, there may not be a write when the framebuffer is `mmap()`ed. Third, the most widespread UI rendering is probably not based on something as trivial as a simple framebuffer. Doing something like this is massive hackery that will take ages to implement and likely break with the next kernel version. It is just not practical.

Comment: All I need to do, that it's allocate my own buffer in the kernel, fill it with image and say display driver draw it. All the same that ordinary framebuffer driver does, excluding interaction with user-space application. I don't need any user-space GUI subsystem, because my picture should be placed on the top of the screen. I really can't do this using kernel framebuffer API?